# Get name from session['email']

Tags: php, html

I have the following problem:

i start a session with my login.php .. bla bla..

now I'm on my Index, logged in as e.g. test@test.com

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?> 

<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION["email"])) 
{ 
echo "Please <a href=\"login.html\">login</a> first"; 
exit; 
} 
?>
```

Now I want to select the name of the logged in account:

i tried something like that but it doesn't works

```
$email = $_SESSION['email']; 
$thename = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM login WHERE email LIKE '$email' LIMIT 1");
```

After this, I want to add it to a <"input">

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php echo $thename; ?>"    style="width:calc(100% - 5px);" />
```

Thank you for helping :)

Tim

Comment: Note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection, in case you didn't know.

Comment: @max oh no i didn't know, but it's only localhost :)

Comment: so whats the problem here?

Comment: i dont get the "name" of the session user

Comment: You are aware that simply assigning a string to a variable does not actually make a database query, right?

Comment: you have to select it first from the db. and please use mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements

Comment: Please can me someone show how to do it right?

Comment: If you lack the most basic knowledge on how to query data from a database, then please go work through some tutorials on the subject.

Comment: nvm google helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as long as I can see you haven't executed any SQL queries to your DB. You need to connect to database and get the result (code is injection-free):

```
// You can skip this part if you've already connected to MySQL

$link = new mysqli($host, $username, $password);

$link->select_db($db_name);

// Prepare query

$sql = $link->prepare('SELECT name FROM login WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1');

// Bind the param

$sql->bind_param('s', $email);

// Execute the query

$sql->execute();

$sql->bind_result($thehome);

$sql->close();

$link->close(); // of course if you need the connection open, just remove this line
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps: SELECT name FROM login WHERE email LIKE '%$email%' LIMIT 1

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I don't know what I was thinking. This answer is invalid and I withdraw it.